# how to check if today is between two dates in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, octobercms

I'd like to check if today's date is between two dates from the database. Here's my code.

```
{% if today < room.price_start_date and today > room.price_end_date %}
<a href="{{'/'|app}}/book/{{room.id}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Book this room</button></a>
{% else %}
<a href="{{'/'|app}}/contact"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Book this room</button></a>
{% endif %}
```

The `today` variable gets its value from this code:

```
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
$this['today'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todayDate));
```

The `price_start_date` and `price_end_date` I get them from database and their columns' type is `Date`

Any idea how to check if `today` is between `room.price_start_date` and `room.price_end_date` in Twig?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the TWIG manual, you can use [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) function.
If no argument is passed, the function returns **the current date**.

So your code might look like this in TWIG:

```
{% if date(room.price_start_date) < date() and date(room.price_end_date) > date() %}
  {# condition met #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Actually I changed the comparison signs to `                                                {% if date(room.price_start_date) < date() and date(room.price_end_date) > date() %}
` and worked.

Many Thanks !

Comment: @AhmedEssam, thanks, you are right, I updated the comparison signs the right way. Feel free to accept the answer, and hope it helps to someone else as well!

Comment: This will only work if both start and end are set. If any of those are "open" or null wont work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\DateTime` instances to compare dates in Twig (as well as PHP).

What is wrong?

> [date('Y-m-d')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function returns a formatted date **string**.

So, you should to change it to `$today = new \DateTime('today');` and pass this instance to Twig template or use `date()` Twig function directly in your condition.

> The `price_start_date` and `price_end_date` I get them from database and their columns' type is Date.

Assuming that these two (`room.price_start_date` and `room.price_end_date`) are instances of `\DateTime`, then your Twig code should work fine.

Comment: It should be noted that `YYYY-MM-DD` date strings (`date('Y-m-d')`) are correctly comparable in PHP  https://3v4l.org/bCfZv  and twig https://twigfiddle.com/opjcw8

Answer (score 0):

Try the date function:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html

You might have to change your code a bit, so I can't advise best.

**EDIT #2**

Sorry I didn't have a chance to look over the docs on the Twig date function, but it's good that @Yonel and @Farside did. @Yonel's points are the ones that I was concerned with, and didn't have time to give a good answer.

If you are using `\DateTime`, then this would be your code changes:

```
{% if date() < date(room.price_start_date) and date() > date(room.price_end_date) %}
    <a href="{{'/'|app}}/book/{{room.id}}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Book this room</button></a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{'/'|app}}/contact">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Book this room</button></a>
{% endif %}
```

I improved the formatting too. I presume you are just checking that the user can click book a room within that timeframe. And your code looks good.

You could add `{{ dump(room.price_start_date) }}` and so on in the DEV environment to debug what your actual dates look like as a troubleshooting technique.

Answer (score 0):

For open dates solution consider extending @Farside solution a bit as follows:

```
    {% if ( date(room.price_start_date) is null or date(room.price_start_date) < date())  and   
          ( date(room.price_end_date)   is null or date(room.price_end_date)   > date()) %}

      {# condition met #}

    {% endif %}
```

Also take into account that if neither start or end is set it will consider everything inside the range.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, use this:

```
{% if start_date <= check_date and check_date <= end_date %}<br>
     ... your code<br>
{% else %}<br>
     ... your code<br>
{% endif %}
```